# How to add Java type to nashorn engine global scope from java?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

Basically I'd like to have the same effect of calling:

```
ScriptEngineManager::put(String key, Object value)
```

but for a Java type. Something like:

```
ScriptEngineManager::put(String key, Class<?> clazz)
```

So that, for instance, after calling:

```
scriptEngineManager.put("MyClass", MyClass.class)
```

I will be able to do:

```
ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("MyClass.myStaticMethod();")
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to invoke Java `static` methods. Maybe there is a simpler way, but I came up with the following.

Let's say you have 2 Java classes `Adder` and `Arithm`:

```
public class JSNashorn {

    public static class Adder {
        int total=0;
        public Adder() {}
        public int add(int x) { return total+=x;}
        public int getTotal() { return total;}
    }

    public static class Arithm {
        public static int sum(int a, int b) {
            return a+b;
        }
        public static int mul(int a, int b) {
            return a*b;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Initialise the JS engine:

```
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine jsEngine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Invocable iv = (Invocable)jsEngine;
```

In order to call Java methods on an instance:

```
    jsEngine.eval("function makeJsObject(nativeObject) { return {nativeObject:nativeObject}; };");

    Object adder = iv.invokeFunction("makeJsObject", new Adder());
    jsEngine.put("adder", adder);
    jsEngine.eval("adder.add = function(x) { return this.nativeObject.add(x); };");
    System.out.println("add: "+iv.invokeMethod(adder, "add", 67));
    System.out.println("add: "+iv.invokeMethod(adder, "add", 33));
```

This print:

```
add: 67
add: 100
```

Now for `static` methods:

```
    jsEngine.eval("function makeJsClass(nativeClass) { return Java.type(nativeClass); };");

    Object arithm = iv.invokeFunction("makeJsClass", "JSNashorn$Arithm");
    jsEngine.put("arithm", arithm);
    jsEngine.eval("sum = function(x,y) { return arithm.sum(x,y); };");
    jsEngine.eval("mul = function(x,y) { return arithm.mul(x,y); };");
    System.out.println("sum: "+iv.invokeFunction("sum", 100, -2));
    System.out.println("mul: "+iv.invokeFunction("mul", 100, -2));
```

This print:

```
sum: 98
mul: -200
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put in this answer!
Anyway, to call a method of an instance, you just need to call `jsEngine.put("adder", adder);`, no need to re-define its methods as javascript functions, you can just call it as `jsEngine.eval("adder.add(33);")`.
For static methods, I came up with a solution similar to yours myself, but I wanted to know if there was a "clean" way to do it...